# Languages with palatal vowel harmony

Tags: phonology, vowel-harmony

The abstract to one of the chapters of *Asymmetries in Vowel Harmony* (I don't have access to the full book) says:

> Palatal harmony is common in, and almost confined to, Finno-Ugric and Altaic languages.

Is there a reason front-back vowel harmony as found in Finnish is seemingly so much rarer than height harmony or ATR harmony? What are the other languages that have it? (I was only able to find the Yokutsan languages as an example of non-"Ural-Altaic" palatal harmony).

Comment: Just to be completely clear, since Finno-Ugric languages are explicitly involved here: Some variants of Sámi have [suprasegmental palatalisation harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolt_Sámi#Suprasegmentals) as a feature, which I’ve also seen referred to as ‘palatal harmony’ for simplicity. That is a different thing from the front–back vowel harmony seen in Finnish, Hungarian, Turkish, etc., and not what this question is about.